# How does the BigQuery command line tool "bq query" stop printing the sql query string for some jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line, google-bigquery, bq

Let's say the following file exists in the current directory:

```
# example1.sql

SELECT 1 AS data
```

When I run `bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --format=csv < example1.sql` I get the expected output:

```
Waiting on bqjob_r1cc6530a5317399f_0000017f2b966269_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE   
data
1
```

But if I run the following query

```
# example2.sql

DECLARE useless_variable_1 STRING DEFAULT 'var_1';
DECLARE useless_variable_2 STRING DEFAULT 'var_2';

SELECT 1 AS data;
```

like this `bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --format=csv < example2.sql` I get the following output:

```
Waiting on bqjob_r501cc26a3d336b7c_0000017f2b97ceb1_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE   
SELECT 1 AS data; -- at [6:1]
data
1
```

As you can see, adding variables caused `bq query` to print the contents of "example2.sql" to stdout, which is not what I want. How can I avoid printing the contents of the file to stdout and instead just return the result of the query like in the first example?

Comment: Hello. The intention to display the queries in the output is to delimit the results of multiple queries, which is similar to the UI’s behaviour. Currently, the `bq` CLI does not offer an option to display only the query results. As a workaround, the `sed` command can be used to extract only query results and omit the queries.

Comment: If this functionality is an important part of your setup, please create a feature request in Google’s Issue Tracker using this [template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162685). You can provide more details and insights about the requirement in the Issue Tracker thread.

Comment: A feature request for this requirement has been created. Sharing it here for posterity. https://issuetracker.google.com/223685280